# Add directive to children from parent directive

Tags: angular

In AngularJS we used to have the `pre` and `post` functions, and the ability to `$compile` templates when needed. There is no way of doing this in Angular (2+), is there?

Specifically, what I want to achieve is, having a template like this:

```
<form myDirective>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
</form>
```

Make `myDirective` add dynamically another directive (say `anotherDirective`) to all the host's children of type `input`. Is that possible somehow?

Comment: Do you want to add dynamic input field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not possible. You cannot assign a directive dynamically, be it in another directive or a full component (a component is considered a directive with a template in Angular).

The only way to dynamically manipulate hard (eg not CSS) DOM properties is by using Renderer2 and accessing the host's element's children in your `myDirective` like this:

```
constructor(private hostEl: ElementRef){}
ngOnInit() {
    if(hostEl.nativeElement.children.length) { 
        hostEl.nativeElement.children.forEach(el => {if (isInput(el) { useRenderer2InSomeWay(el) })})
    }
}
```

But what I would do is either to put `anotherDirective` in each input directly, so you don't have to access children or (even better) consider not using a directive at all but just define a wrapper component for `<input>`:

```
        <my-input-wrapper
          <input
            [config]="someConfigToApplyToInputInside"
            [formControlName]="'foobar'">
          </input>
        </my-input-wrapper>
```

and in the MyInputWrapperComponent:

```
@ContentChildren('input') inputs: QueryList<any>;
```

With ContentChild/ContentChildren you can access FormControls from the surrounding component but still delegate ui-stuff like custom placeholders and icons you want to have in the input, to the wrapper-component.